# simple set problem.Why I am wrong?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Which set is this picture explaining.

[image]

> 1.$A\cap B\cap C$
>
> 2.$(C-A) \cup (C-B)$
>
> 3.$(A-C) \cap (A-B)$
>
> 4.$C-((C-A) \cup(C-B))$

Our teacher give the answer $4$ but I wrote $1$. What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: 1 is the correct answer.

Comment: There must be a printing error in the answer. Printers fail sometimes.

Comment: Are you sure our teacher is an intellegent person.

Comment: @Mc Cheng yes you are right.It is edited.

Comment: In this case, both 1 and 4 are correct...

Comment: Yes I think so I am sure $1$ is correct.

Comment: Now that you've edited both 1 and 4 are correct !

Comment: yeah but it is impossible.

Comment: There are a lot of impossible things in math.

Comment: Yes you are right:).

Answer (score 2):

1 and 4 are the correct answers.  So what's wrong with your answer is that you did't say "1 and 4".

Comment: No he says the answer is only $1$

Comment: Then his answer is also wrong.  Are you sure answer 1 is not $A\cup B\cup C$?

Comment: No it isn't.Also $1$ is better answer .

Comment: 1 is a simpler answer.  "Better" is a subjective statement. If simpler is better then it is better. If demonstrating that complicated set membership statements can be equivalent to simple ones is desirable then answer 4 is better.  The answer to the question posed above, is that the diagram is explaining the sets described in 1 and 4.

Comment: @Qwerty the question is "Why was my answer wrong?"  The answer to that question is "Your answer was wrong because the correct answer is '1 and 4' while your answer was '1'". Taha's answer is wrong because it was incomplete. So it exactly does provide an answer the question.